# How can i execute a promise after the endpoint response?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, promise

I need to keep a promise executing after the response has already been returned to the browser. In my case, I only want to convert a video and keep the output file at the OS without using `await`, for performance reasons. For example:

```
function endPointHandler(req, res) {
  // ... sync stuff ...

  processVideoConvertion(req); // this method will return a promise that needs to be executed after the response.

  return res.json({ message: 'Success' });

}
```

As it shows above, I don't need any data of the returning value of the `processVideoConvertion` method, there is a way that I can do that?

Comment: What you have will not block (though as noted below it doesn't handle if that promise throws an error, so you should have a .catch hanging off of there to handle the error, even if it's just to log it locally.)  But as written, it won't stop at `processVideoConvertion` and immediately return the response without waiting for the promise to resolve or reject.

Answer (score 1):

You can .then and .catch to check status, the process will be running in the background after sending a response.

**Note:** Don't use async/await it will wait until the video is converted(process done).

```
function endPointHandler(req, res) {
  // ... sync stuff ...

  processVideoConvertion(req)
    .then((data) => console.log("Video Converted", data))
    .catch((e) => console.error("Video Conversion Failed", e));

  return res.json({ message: "Success" });
}
```